# Visual Studio Code - AZURE COSMOS DB extension - Invalid credentials provided (Error 401)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb

I have been testing **Visual Studio Code - AZURE COSMOS DB** extension
in combination with **Graph API** options and encountered **Invalid credentials provided (Error 401)** error.
I had previously created an existing **Azure Cosmos DB Graph API** project on **Azure Portal** which had already generated
**URI**, **PRIMARY KEY** as well as **PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING**. I had repeated the same process over and over,in many occasions, even managed to use  the **dtui**-**data migration tool** to seed data and everything
always went smoothly. However trying to connect to **Graph API** database through
**Visual Studio Code** - **AZURE COSMOS DB extension Graph Explorer** user interface seemed a bit more complicated than I thought.
When I wanted to provide an **Attached Database Account** then **Visual Studio Code** command prompted to

```
Select a Data Account API...
```

I selected `Graph`.
A next **Visual Studio Code** command them prompts to

`Enter the connection string for your database account(Press 'Enter' to confirm or 'Escape' to cancel`.

I then provided the **PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING** of my project using similar format pattern:

```
AccountEndpoint=https://<my-project-endpoint>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=<my-project-primary-key==>;
```

I could then see the proper `database` and `collection` of the **Graph API** I had created earlier on **Azure Portal**,

[image]

though when clicking on collection to launch and display the graph explorer, I ended up with following **Invalid credentials provided (Error 401)** message:

[image]

Any hints on how to cope with this issue would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check your conneciton string, it must be wrong

Comment: Nope. Primary Connection String provided is fine otherwise I wouldn't even have been able to connect to both database and collection displayed in image I showed above. An error would have been thrown earlier in that case saying it's either wrong or not properly formatted which I doubt is the case here as I tested it running Console Application and it's fine. Problem is elsewhere in this case and wouldn't be surprised it may even be a bug with the extension. Remember a lot of VSCode extension features are still in Preview  Anyway I won't waste too much time on that.Mainly curiosity testing

Comment: @PeteZaria I hit the same error as you last week and I deleted the graph db and create it again and everything is fine. Could you try it?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Jay. So I guess I wasn't the only one. Something must have gone wrong somewhere. As I mentioned the tool is still in Preview, so I guess we may expect a couple of unwanted strange behaviors when creating account from VS Code. So I deleted everything and started all from scratch. New database and collections created on Azure Portal appeared in the list and I was able to have access to each and every one using Graph Explorer this time. Great.

Comment: I gave up using vscode extension instead I am starting to use https://www.bruttin.com/CosmosDbExplorer/.

Answer (score 0):

If this graph account created before Graph GA'ed in February (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-graph-api-now-generally-available/), then you need to create a new account and try again.  The gremlin support in Azure is much better with GA graph accounts. You can also bring this issue up on our GitHub repro here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cosmosdb/issues.

Stephen

Comment: This is more of a clarification-question than an answer (though it has some small answerish elements...). https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: I guess you're right... Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB team strongly suggests using Gremlin.Net as they mentioned they would no longer invest energy in further Microsoft.Azure.Graphs packages library. None of the released versions ever gone beyond the -preview stage. I also found formatting bugs with 0.3.1 version so I'm using Gremlin.Net from now on. Not perfect as it doesn't fully support bytecode but we're getting there. As for VS Code. Everything now runs smoothly. I'm using latest VS Code version with latest extensions 